# How do you believe the deduction rules in natural language are correct?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know the soundness of a first order language is proved in natural language by natural language deduction rules. For example, to prove $\phi \implies \phi \lor \psi $ is correct,
we construct the following deduction sequence in natural language:

1. model m and assignment s satisfy $\phi$
2. model m and assignment s satisfy $\phi$ or $\psi$   (a deduction rule in natural language)
3. model m and assignment s satisfy $ \phi \lor \psi $

We use a natural language deduction rule that is similar to the FOL deduction rule being proved ( $\phi \implies \phi \lor \psi $) to derive from 1) to 2). But I did not see a proof for the natural language deduction rules themselves. I don't think the natural language deduction rules do not need some kind of proof, as you know, people had used the deduction rule: for all $x$, $P(x) \implies$ there exists $x$, $P(x)$, for thousands of years until it's proved wrong by modern logic.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence: what do you mean when you say "the soundness of a first order language is proved in natural language by natural language deduction rules"? Anyway, have you heard of [soundness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Logical_systems)?

Comment: Re your last sentence: with standard semantics for FOL with non-empty domains the rule is sound.

Comment: Having said that, the natural language logic survived to thousands of years of scrutiny by the best mind. Thus, they are correct.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes, I know that.  Please see added content in the question.

Comment: @peter "I don't think the natural language deduction rules do not need some kind of proof" I think the logical positivists tried to argue that they are true because of convention; however in Quine's famous paper 'Truth by Convention' he argued that it suffers from infinite regress.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know I am nit-picking here; but when you say natural language logic does that include distributivity of conjunction over disjunction? If so, I think that has proven to be false in the context of quantum mechanics

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, you wrote: "natural language logic survived to thousands of years of scrutiny by the best mind".  In fact, it didn't;  see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4833004/72694).

Answer (score 3):

Until Frege, it was common to assume that a phrase such as "all flying dragons are blue" implies the existence of a flying dragon.  Remarkably, Lewis Carroll in one of his books on logic games uses the universal quantifier in this way (this was only a few decades before Frege).  Notice, however, that most logic books start with a specific list of logical transformations and formalisations of metalanguage rules that are allowed.  These certainly don't include Lewis Carroll's trick.  The confidence we have in such systems is the result of extensive practice that did not result in contradictions; there is no absolute guarantee that this is so.  So, the rules of deduction in the metatheory are assumed to be correct because we haven't run into trouble with them.  This is of course connected to the famous quandry with Hilbert's program.